# Should the cloth part of ski gloves be treated before use?

Tags: clothing, cold-weather

I know that the leather part (if any) of ski gloves should be treated with some grease such as [Hestra Balm](https://hestragloves.com/sport/en-us/gloves/accessories/hestra-leather-balm/000/) or [Sno Seal](http://www.atsko.com/sno-seal-wax-8-oz-jar/).  But should the cloth (non-leather) part of the glove (again, if any), like most modern gloves have, be treated with something to prevent moisture/cold penetration?

Comment: Well I am pretty sure: No.

Comment: I don't think you can generalize all ski gloves like this. Maybe a particular brand or material, but not 'ski gloves.'

Answer (score 3):

Most ski gloves will have a waterproof/breathable layer (Gore-Tex or something similar, they should be labelled to say what it is). In my experience new gloves also seem to have a water repellant on the fabric to help water drops fall off before they get to the Gore-Tex. This surface water repellant will wear away and could be refreshed with various spray-on products [(products I've used)](http://www.nikwax.com/en-us/productselector/waterproofing.php).

Ideally you should be able to put your gloves (or any hard shell clothing) under a running faucet and have all the water run off. Gore-Tex is great stuff, but still better when it's dry on the outside.